# How to get the list of recently logged in user in asp.net core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the list of recently logged in user ,  how can I get the list of recently logged in user in asp.net core MVC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create model class:

```
 public class LoginEntry
 { 
      [Key]
      public string EntryID { get; set; }
      public string UserID { get; set; }
      public ApplicationUser User { get; set; } //represents the user who was logged

      public DateTime? TimeOfLastLogin { get; set; } //time when the user logged last time
  }
```

So you need some service that do entry when user was logged:

```
public class LoginEntryService
{
  public void DoEntry(ApplicationUser user)
  {
   var entry = dbcontext.LoginEntries.SingleOrDefault(e => e.UserID == userID);
   if (entry == null) //if Entry for the user does not exist then create it
       entry = new LoginEntry() {UserID = user.ID};
   entry.TimeOfLastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow; //update the last login time

   if (entry.ID == null)
       dbcontext.LoginEntries.Add(entry);

   dbcontext.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

You can call DoEnty method when the user is logging from, e.g., controller or user repository  instance